# Code repeated in multiple exception blocks

Tags: python, exceptions

I'm starting to notice this pattern throughout some of my code:

```
try:
    some_func()
except FirstException as err:  # known possible err
    # log err
    notify_user(err)
except SecondException as err:  # known possible err
    # log err
    notify_user(err)
except Exception as err:  # unexpected err to prevent crash
    # log err
    notify_user(err)
finally:
    # close logs
```

It should be noted that `some_func` does not explicitly raise these exceptions, but calls other methods that may propagate them back up the call stack. While its clean and clear that each exception caught will get its own logging (which presumably has a unique message), they all call the same `notify_user`. Therefore, this structure is not DRY, so I thought:

```
try:
    some_func()
except Exception as err:  # catch all (presumably) exceptions
    if isinstance(err, FirstException):
        # log err
    elif isinstance(err, SecondException):
        # log err
    else:
        # log err
    notify_user(err)
finally:
    # close logs
```

While also clear that logging is specific to the desired error caught, its now DRY.

But doesn't this defeat the point of knowing know exception types by trying to catch all exceptions and using conditionals to identify which is caught? Broad exception catching seems "okay" in concept, but I'm concerned it could lead to some unforeseen consequences later.

Comment: Normally catching all exceptions could be a problem, but here you're doing that in either case. So the usual objections don't apply. I think either variant is fine.

Comment: @amon Is it abnormal to have the "catch all exception" portion at the program root to prevent it from crashing? Say in a Java `main` method perhaps?

Comment: A catch-all at the top level or at another failure boundary is very common and often absolutely necessary. But you should note that Python's exception hierarchy is a bit weird – the root is not `Exception` but `BaseException`. Whether you should catch those as well depends on the context.

Comment: You could use multi except like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470428/catch-multiple-exceptions-in-one-line-except-block

Comment: Do you have control over the exception hierarchy? If so you could institute a base class which can be caught and logged in a single catch here.

Comment: @Minato using the multi-except syntax still results in using `isinstance`, plus if I kept `Exception` from the grouping, I'd have to have another block to handle that. My second example is, in essence, a multi-except (`Exception` will catch all anticipated, plus unanticipated).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Catching a bare Exception is mostly bad practice, but this would solve your problem as I have understood it.

```
EXCEPTION_SPECIFIC_LOG_MSG = {
    FirstException: 'first exception',
    SecondException: 'second exception',
    Exception: 'bare exception'
}

try:
    some_func()
except (FirstException, SecondException, Exception) as e:
    print(EXCEPTION_SPECIFIC_LOG_MSG[type(e)])
    notify_user(e)
```

Comment: I agree that catching the bare `Exception` is generally a bad practice, but this is at the root of the program (analogous to Java's `main`), so the bare catch is there to prevent a program crashing and gracefully notifying the user (along with crash dumping).

Comment: Note also that this has very little to do with "DRY". Dry is important when critical logic is involved. You don't want to have your business repeated all over the code. Handling exceptions is a very corner case that might justify blocks like the one you dislike. On the other hand, to make these blocks DRY you would have to encapsulate these blocks into a sort of handler for further reuse. But @Minato answer is, IMO, a cleaner and elegant way to solve your main concern. I would get rid of the map and I would just print e.message. If any.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution looks ok to me. Alternatively (not necessarily "better"), here is a DRY version without using `isinstance`:

```
lasterr=None
try:
    some_func()
except FirstException as err:  # known possible err
    # log err
    lasterr=err
except SecondException as err:  # known possible err
    # log err
    lasterr=err
except Exception as err:  # unexpected err to prevent crash
    # log err
    lasterr=err
finally:
   if lasterr is not None:
      notify_user(err)
    # close logs
```

Of course, the statement `lasterr=err` is repeated here, but since this does not contain any real "logic", this does not count as a DRY violation. Those statements are usually not as likely to change as a function call `notify_user(err)`, so the goal of DRY to reduce the number of places where changes will happen is fulfilled.

You did not show us the logging code, but it might be also a good idea not to do the real logging at all places where `# log err` occurs, only remember the specific logging message in a variable, and do the logging in the `finally` section as well.

Comment: I had this at one point but that the boolean variable addition and reuse was still DRY. Normally I don't catch the generic Exception, but this is at the program root and would prefer to handle it gracefully rather than crash. Is that an anti-pattern or fairly common?

Comment: @pstatix:  "boolean variable addition"? No idea what you mean. And to your second question (which is independent from the alternative implementations): handling generic exceptions gracefully at the program's root is a fairly common strategy for many systems. If it is suitable or not depends on the context, what kind of program you are writing, what consequences a bug might have and how information about bugs or unexpected exceptions can be communicated to a developer when they occur.  (Just noted amon told you the same - I fully agree to what he wrote).

Comment: Sorry, poor wording, "with the addition of a variable (i.e. lasterr)", at first I read that you were setting it to `True`, not `err`.

Comment: Why would logging at the `# log err` not be best?